# How do I get the quotient as int and remainder as a floating point in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

On my calculator when I do 18/7 I get 2.5714285714285714285714285714286.
From my super limited Math skills 2 is the quotient and .5714285714285714285714285714286 is the remainder.

How can I model this in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the remainder be `4`? `18%7 === 4`.

Comment: Perhaps remainder isn't the correct name. I want that floating point bit.

Comment: The name would the `fractional part of the quotient` as opposed to the `integer part of the quotient`.  The `remainder` value of `4` comes from `7 * .5714285714285714285714285714286` if you were wondering.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
var floatingPointPart = (18/7) % 1;
var integerPart = Math.floor(18/7);
```

Comment: Why not `Math.trunc`? Then it also works with negative numbers.

Comment: Yea, `Math.floor` will bring it towards the negative end, so `-3.3` becomes `-4`, unlike `Math.trunc`, which brings it to `-3` (dropping decimals as expected for a truncation). To be fair the answer was made before ES6 became standard in 2015... See more of Math.trunc here: https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-math.trunc

Answer (score 23):

Math.floor has the problem of rounding of the result to wrong direction in case of negative number it would be better to use bitwise operation to obtain interger quotients.

```
var quot = ~~(num/num1)
```

Hopefully this works for you!

Comment: All because the bit-wise invert operator forces it back to integer. :) love it!

Comment: One needs to be careful with this because it only works with integers of absolute value < 2^31. For numbers greater than 2^31 one will get unexpected results ([bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise)  explains how numbers with more than 32 bits in their binary representation get truncated before applying bitwise operators ..

Answer (score 10):

```
var rawQuotient = 18/7;
var remainder = rawQuotient % 1;
var quotient = rawQuotient - remainder;
```

In most mathematics, there's no real need for distinction between the fractional portion and the whole portion, especially given that the whole thing can be expressed as a fraction (18/7ths), as a real number, or as a mix of integers and fractions (2 and 4/7ths).

When you get into programming or engineering, or some other derivative, you have definite uses for the separation; but the quotient is really the whole thing, integer and fraction, however you choose to represent that.

Comment: This (uses simple arithmetic ) answer is better than the accepted answer which depends on Math library.

Comment: Here, quotient may have rounding errors induced through remainder.

Answer (score 5):

We can use simple mathematics to get answer using only `/` & `%` operator.

Consider 'num1' as first value & 'num2' as second value. Then :

```
var Quotient = (num1 - (num1 % num2)) / num2;

var FloatingPoint = (num1 % num2) / num2;
```

Comment: I like this answer better than accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

2 is the quotient (or integer part of the result), 4 is the remainder, and 4/7 is the floating point part of the result, which the OP is requesting.

```
var result = (18/7);
var integerPart = Math.floor(result);
var floatingPointPart = result - integerPart;
```

integerPart and floatingPointPart are the requested values.

Answer (score 1):

```
var decimals = float - (float | 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The quotient and remainder can be found using [integer division](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) and the [modulo (`%`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) respectively.

```js
let quotient = 18n / 7n;
let remainder = 18 % 7;

console.log(`${quotient}, ${remainder}`);
```

Floating point numbers can be converted to big integers:

```js
let dividend = 18;
let divisor = 7;
let quotient = BigInt(dividend) / BigInt(divisor);
let remainder = dividend % divisor;

console.log(`${quotient}, ${remainder}`);
```

Alternatively, use [`Math.trunc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc):

```js
let quotient = Math.trunc(18 / 7);
let remainder = 18 % 7;

console.log(`${quotient}, ${remainder}`);
```

Answer (score -1):

In the decimal number `2.5714285714285716`,
the *quotient*, which also is the *whole part*, is `2`
and the *decimal*/*fractional* part is `0.5714285714285716` or `0.5714285714285716`
but actually, the *remainder* is 4.000000000000002 or 4

```js
let decimal = 18 / 7;
let quotient = ~~decimal;
let dec_remainder = decimal - quotient;
let dec_remainder0 = decimal % 1;
let remainder = dec_remainder * 7;
let remainder0 = 18 % 7;

document.body.innerHTML = "In the decimal number "+decimal+",<br/>
the quotient, which also is the whole part, is "+quotient+"<br/>
and the decimal/fractional part is "+dec_remainder+ " or " + dec_remainder0 + "<br/>
but actually, the remainder is "+remainder+" or "+remainder0 ;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

You can determine the quotient in [several](https://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/page.php?id=58&title=fastest-alternative-to-math-floor-in-javascript) ways.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, 2 is the quotient and 4/18 is the remainder.

```
Math.divideby= function(d, dby){
    var q= Math.floor(d/dby), r= d-(q*dby);
    return r== 0? q:q+' and '+r+'/'+d;
}
```

**Math.divideby(18,7)**

/*  returned value: (String) */

**2 and 4/18**

Comment: That is incorrect. 2 is the quotient, but 4 is [the remainder](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/remainder.html).